# Convert floating number to "prime" fraction

Tags: matlab

Sorry for a possibly misleading title.

Given a floating point input "A", we need factor it as

```
Q = A + B/C
```

where A is integer part of Q, so basically fix(Q), and B & C must be coprime to one other.

Example:

```
Q = 14.7419 => Q = 14 + 23/31
```

So that

```
A = 14, B = 23, C = 31
```

Is there a way to get B and C with intrinsic matlab functions? If not, I would appreciate a guidance in the right direction :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `A` the input, or `Q`? Are you looking for [`rats`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rats.html)?

Comment: @pncln You need to realize that binary floating point cannot represent the fractional part of most decimal numbers exactly, so your problem as stated is ambiguous. E.g., the 0.7419 fractional part shown above cannot be represented exactly. You will have to make decisions about how to handle this discrepancy, and maybe the rats( ) function proposed by beaker is the best way to go.

Comment: E.g., [N,D]=numden(sym(Q-fix(Q))) will simply yield 7419 and 10000 for the above because the sym engine is trying to match the ratio to what it thinks you probably meant in the decimal realm, not what is actually stored in binary.

Comment: To get the exact rational fraction for what is actually stored in the floating point binary, you could use [N,D]=numden(sym(Q-fix(Q),'f')), which would yield 417652570443271 and 562949953421312 for the above Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here would not be the `rats` function as suggested by beaker under the question, but the `rat` function:

```
Q = 14.7419;
A = fix( Q )
[B,C] = rat( Q-A, 0.001)
```

The second argument to `rat` is the tolerance.
For further details please refer to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html.

Comment: That would be a perfect solution for my case if it did not show the fraction in a "continued form" like 1/(2+(2/(23+.....).

Comment: @pncln: Which MATALB version are you using? With the two outputs ```[N,D] = rat(___)```,  I actually get the numerator and the denominator and not the continued form. Have you tested my code? For me, (version R2020a) the continued form is only shown when using only one argument.

Comment: Wow, interestingly, assigning `rat( Q-A, 0.001)` to a single variable makes it continued. `{B, C] worked though. Thanks a lot.